# why nth-child in find_by_css returning nothing?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap "href" link from this html code :

[image]

My code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from splinter import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as tt

ar=webdriver.Chrome('/Users/exepaul/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver')
url="https://www.python.org/about/"
browser=Browser("chrome")
browser.visit(url)

find_h=browser.find_by_css('div[class="medium-widget success-story-category last"]:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > a')
for i in find_h:
    print(i["href"])
```

But it returning nothing

Comment: looks like you are mixing `xpath` and `css`, try this instead: `'div.medium-widget.success-story-category.last:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > a'`

Comment: same result , nothing returning.

Comment: This `'div.medium-widget.success-story-category.last > ul > li:first-child > a'` seems to work for me. Since there is only one `<ul>` and `<a>` Tag in it's parent, there is no need for 'nth-child(1)' ... and if so, there is a `:first-child` pseudo class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hello:nth-child(3)` doesn't select the 3rd nested div of hello class instead it select the third hello class when there are three "hello" class with same name.

So that's why i was doing mistake there are two classes with same name and so i have to do `'div[class="medium-widget success-story-category last"]:nth-child(2)>p'` it will select `<p>` text and when i do:

```
find_h=browser.find_by_css('div[class="medium-widget success-story-category last"]:nth-child(2) > ul  > li:nth-child(2) > a'
```

its working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

try with the following,

```
div[class="medium-widget success-story-category last"]:nth-child(2)>ul:nth-child(n)>li:nth-child(1) > a
```

Comment: I have some confusion , when i do `'div[class="medium-widget success-story-category last"]:nth-child(2)>p'` it gives me <p> text so it means `'div[class="medium-widget success-story-category last"]:nth-child(2)>` is `<p>` tag there but in your answer nth-child(2) is selecting `ul` how ?

Comment: because you are using >p in your selector

Comment: can you explain little more in your answer that what happen when we do "class : nth-child(2)" it select second child of parent class or it select second class from whole document ?

Comment: also explain please which element  are nth-child(1) , nth-child(2) , nth-child(3) in code  and what is meaning of nth-child(n) how it works and when to use this ?